# Flutter ListView.builder resets scroll position when new items are added

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am working on a Flutter app that uses a **`ListView.builder`** to display a list of containers. I have implemented pagination, where new containers are fetched and added to the list when the user reaches the end of the current list. However, every time new containers are added, the scroll position resets to the top of the list, which is not the desired behavior.

I have followed the suggestion to use the **`AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`** and set **`addAutomaticKeepAlives`** to **`true`** for the **`ListView.builder`**, but the issue persists. Here is an example of my code:

```
class ViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    const ViewScreen({super.key});
    @override
    State<ViewScreen> createState() => ViewScreenState();
}

class ViewScreenState extends State<ViewScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  static final List<Widget> containers = [];
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> previousCards = [ //I have used it as a dummy database in real I will request an API that will return some data in it that is used in the container that is displayed];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadContainers();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        // User has reached the end of the list, trigger "load more" action
        loadContainers();
        _addAllPreviousCards();
      }
    });
  }

  void loadContainers() async {
    previousCards.clear();
    // call the API again to fetch more containers
    // starting from containers.length
    if(containers.length < allContainers.length) {
      for (int i = containers.length; i < containers.length + 6; i++) {
        previousCards.add(allContainers[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  void _addAllPreviousCards() async{
    for(int i = 0;i<previousCards.length;i++) {
      setState(() {
        containers.add(
          MyContainer(
            text: previousCards[i]['request'][text],
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget content =Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListView.builder(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: containers.length ,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return containers[index];
              }
            )
          ),
        ],
      );
   return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            color:const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
              child: content
            ),
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Am I missing something in my implementation? Is there a different approach to preserving the scroll position when new items are added to a **`ListView.builder`**? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used it for pagination to call api its does not scroll automatically.

```
   _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _homePageController.loadMoreItems();
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @AnonymousFromYT and @Saad. what is this `_homePageController` I can't use this in my code as it gives an error of undefined name